# Postgre SQL Schema Bind of Connection

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, database-connection

we have a presentation of a java gui handling a postgresql database.

On the presentation-server we have some schemas and one is reserved for our group.

My problem now is in binding a Schema to the connection, so that over the whole process the schema is bound. Here is what i have so far, but the c.setSchema() doesn't seems to be implemented, maybe there are other ways.

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://" + host + ":"
    + port + "/" + databaseName, username, password);

    c.setAutoCommit(false);
    c.setSchema("b7");
```

Thanks Stefan Sprenger

EDIT( FIRST TRY):

```
c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://" + host + ":"
            + port + "/" + databaseName+"?searchpath=b7", username, password);
```

no error but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by simply adding a schema.table ..

as an example i give the schema as input parameter and store it to String schema.

if i call a query like:

```
Select * from TABLE;
```

it looks now like

```
Select * from schema.TABLE;
```

and it works ;)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that is necessary.  Wish there was a way to pass searchpath as a parameter to the JDBC url connection string, that way I wouldn't have to prepend all my table names in all my statements.

Answer (score 1):

this url format  `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?searchpath=myschema` seems to never had made it to the official driver, instead you'll have to execute this statement `set search_path to 'schema'` after you make the connection.

Comment: i already tried this, not working :( .. i edited my question so you can see my second try

Comment: are you using the latest driver?

Comment: 9.3 - 1100.jdbc41.jar